# Why Enum[Enum.member] is undefined at codepen.io typescript playground?

Tags: typescript, codepen

I just planned to check some type settings using TypeScript playground at codepen.io
and surprisingly faced the following

```
enum Order {
  Asc = 'asc',
  Desc = 'desc'
}

console.log(Order[Order.Asc]); // undefined in codepen.io playground
```

Of course it results in `Asc` when compiled with webpack etc.

Comment: [The error message](https://i.imgur.com/4voL2KL.png) seems clear. There is no `Order.asc` which is what you are trying to access with `Order[Order.Asc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings

> ...an enum is compiled into an object that stores both forward (name ->
> value) and reverse (value -> name) mappings.
> [...]
> **Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping**
> **generated at all.**

This is how reverse mapping works with numbers:

```
enum Order {
  Asc,
  Desc 
}

Order.Asc // 0
Order[Order.Asc] // "Asc"
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought reverse mapping should work independent of types for enum member values.